# Shadow with GDlib

Tags: php, gdlib

I'm working on auto making of icons from big images, using GDlib. Icons should be with round angles and space beyond angles should be transparent. My icons look very nice and beautifull, and the only thing I need to add is shadow. For now my main idea is to make a transparent image with this shadow and to impose it over my icon. Are there any other/better solutions? What's the best way to do this ?

Comment: I have done this, when your designer has the appropriate skill set and cares for his work this works great. But it's really up to your shadow template to nail this.

Comment: Just read it again: Big images... that might not work so well, in my experience the output is not the best and targeting a 16x16 Format from 256x256 might be problematic.

Comment: hm, precisely as I thought ! Just was curious about other possibilities.

Comment: I guess we have a little missunderstood here. My plan is: 1. to ask my designer to make a 120x120 transparent image with needed shadow. 2 save it somewhere on server. 3. get image from users. 4. scale it to 120x120 and add transperancy, round corners, antialiasing(this is already done). 5. overlay the picture designer made on the picture I got from paragraph 4. 6. ... profit ?
I really don't see why the output should be bad. I am just curious about other possibilities.

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php is very capable - you should get close. Call it from http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: Scaling might become a problem, because the output will not match what professional tools would provide. GDLib's last release was 2007, and it's Open Source. The crucial reality is that Adobe has more manpower and a better algorithm. Just try it it's a 5-10 Liner and you can compare it with Photoshops output.

Comment: 1. Many thanks for pointing me to imagick ! Maybe you should post this in answers, not in comments(I'm not sure about this)
2. :) This is not a question, that the photoshop is much more powerful and has great resizing algorithms. I just want to say that output quality is acceptable, especially when the output size is 120x120, so it is indistinguishable from photoshop in fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to manage this using imagick, even more, I have found an example of what I need http://valokuva.org/?paged=3.